# Tomcat with Puppet taking user's choice

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I want to install tomcat with puppet which while installation should take user's input wherethe catalina_home should be and what port should the installation take place. How can we pass user's input in puppet?

Comment: start from the exist tomcat module download from https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can take user input on how things should be installed using parameters.

You can also leverage existing Puppet modules that other people have written to make things easier.

I'd recommend the [Puppetlabs Tomcat repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-tomcat), you can either clone it manually to your environment or run `puppet module install puppetlabs-tomcat`

Using this module you can specify `$catalina_home` and `$port`.